# Linear Operator on Hilbert Space $l(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be the linear operator on $l(\mathbb Z)$ defined for $u=\{u_k\}_{k \in \mathbb Z}$ as

$(Au)_k = \sum_{h=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_{k,h}u_h$

where $a_{k,h}=\frac{1}{(k-h)2}$ for $h \not= k$, and $a_{k,k}=0$.

Show that $A$ is continuous but is not compact.

I think we would like to show that it is bounded when $\|u\|=1$. Since the standard orthonormal base $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$ we could show that $Ae_n \not\to 0$ to prove that it is not compact.

Thanks.

Comment: Your approach sounds fine.  Where is it that you run into trouble?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think I have problems with 2 variables, also when it comes to integrals like in another question I just posted. In this exercise If I don't go wrong I have to discuss the convergence of $\sum_k\sum_h\frac{1}{(h-k)^4}$ to show boundness.

Comment: You're right about boundedness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Continuous:** Note that
$$
\|Au\|^2  = \sum_k \left(\sum_h a_{k,h} u_h\right)^2 \leq 
\sum_k \left(\left(\sum_h a_{k,h}^2\right) \|u\|^2\right)
$$

**Not Compact:** Note that $(Ae_n)_k = a_{k,n}$.  Thus, we note that for any $n$, we have $(Ae_n)_{n-1} = 1$, so that $\|Ae_n\| \geq 1$.

Conclude that $A e_n \not \to 0$.